# Sending RAW XML to update order status

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, magento-1.9.3.3

I'm trying to update some order statuses via the API.

Currently making use of Magento v1.9.3.3

I'm sending it to http://www.mytestserver.com/index.php/api/soap/

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:call soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">valid-key-here</sessionId>
         <orderIncrementId xsi:type="xsd:string">189</orderIncrementId>
         <status xsi:type="xsd:string">complete</status>
         <comment xsi:type="xsd:string">some stuff here</comment>
         <notify xsi:type="xsd:string">false</notify>      
         <resourcePath xsi:type="xsd:string">order.addComment</resourcePath>
      </urn:call>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

No matter what status or increment ID we apply, we always get

   
      
         100
         Requested order not exists.

Trying this via soapUI and we can see our keys are correct, but can't understand why we are getting this generic message.

Comment: Could you specify what version of Magento you are working with? That would help people to understand more about your issue and therefore increase changes of getting an useful answer to your question.

Comment: thank you for the nudge, I have just updated the post with the version number

Comment: Great, based on that I have also added some relevant tags. This way it is easier for people to apply filters and find this question.

Comment: Is '189' the order id or increment id of the order you're testing with?

Comment: the 189 isnt the incremental id, but we have tried the incremental ID and any other numbers we can find, yet they all return the same error